# Inject Entity manager issue [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to using JPQL queries so I need to use Entity Manager.

I'm using Spring so I create an EntityManagerFactory following a Spring tutorial:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa

So I add this bean to my WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml, following the added bean for em factory:

```
    <beans:bean id="hibernateProperties" class="java.util.Properties">
  <beans:constructor-arg index="0">
     <beans:props>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>
     </beans:props>
  </beans:constructor-arg>
```

```
<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
</beans:property>
<beans:property name="jpaProperties" ref="hibernatePropertiesBean"/>
<beans:property name="packagesToScan">
    <beans:list>
        <beans:value>dao</beans:value>
    </beans:list>
</beans:property>
```

```
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```

And inject it in my DAO Impl:

```
@Repository("productDAO")
public class ProductDAOImpl extends GenericDaoHibernateImpl<Product, Integer>
    implements ProductDAO {

private EntityManagerFactory emf;

@PersistenceUnit
public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    this.emf = emf;
}
```

Trying to run a query:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
@Transactional
public List<Product> getProductsList() {

List<Product> result = new ArrayList<Product>();
EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
...
```

But an Exception is occurred: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

This is my /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="productBean" class="controller.ProductBean">
        <beans:property name="productService" ref="productService"> </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>model.Product</beans:value>
                <beans:value>model.ProductDescription</beans:value>
                <beans:value>model.Language</beans:value>
                <beans:value>model.ProductDescriptionId</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="productDao" class="dao.ProductDaoImpl"/>

    <beans:bean id="productService" class="service.ProductServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="productDao" ref="productDao">  </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


  <!-- bean post-processor for JPA annotations -->
  <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:annotation-config />


    <context:component-scan base-package="dao">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" />
    </context:component-scan>


   <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
   </beans:bean>
   </beans:beans>
```

What's my issue?

Comment: I would suggest injecting an `EntityManager` using `@PersistenceContext` instead. That way spring can manage the transactions instead of you having to do that manually.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum I already tried but it doesn't work due to spring, can you post a sample of how to please

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. What doesn't work exactly? I would also suggest using Spring Data JPA instead of (re)inventing your own generic dao.

Comment: @M.Deinum I already added both EntityManager using PersistenceContext and Spring Data JPA in Maven I updated my question with full applicationContext.xml

Comment: You don't have an entitymanagerfactory in there only a session factory... Why are you mixing things...

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum I cleaned my applicationContext and updated my post.How can I now inject Entity Manager using SessionFactory for Hbernate too?

Comment: Why do you try to use both? That isn't needed... You are only complicating things.

Comment: Because I'm using Hibernate and for certain query I have to use JPQL with an Entity Manager instance so I'm unable to perform It, so what I have to do?

Comment: Why use both? What is it you need plain hibernate for that an `EntityManager` cannot do. You now have 2 managers managing same entities which can lead to very strange results.